# Numpy: concat/expand 2D arrays based on matches in a column. How to eliminate for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a more "Numpy" way to perform an operation to expand and concatenate data from one array to another with repeating terms.

**Example Data**

I want `a` and `b` to look like `c` in the end:

```
a = np.array(((0, 13), (0, 14), (1, 15), (1, 16), (2, 17)))
b = np.array(((0, 415, 666), (1, 286, 583), (2, 777, 32), (3, 663, 12)))

c = np.array(((0, 13, 415, 666), (0, 14, 415, 666), (1, 15, 286, 583), (1, 16, 286, 583), (2, 17, 777, 32)))
```

In my example data, note that the first column is an "index" of sorts with multiple repetitions for some in array `a`.  Also note that `b` contains unused indices.

**MWE of working code**

I am currently performing this task with a combination of `np.repeat` and np.tile`inside a`for`` loop.  However, this is inefficient:

```
c = np.empty((0, 4))
for i in np.unique(a[:, 0]):
    foo = a[np.where(a[:, 0] == i)]
    bar = b[np.where(b[:, 0] == i)]
    output = np.vstack((output, np.column_stack((np.repeat(foo, np.size(bar, 0), 0), np.tile(bar, (np.size(foo, 0), 1))))))
```

**The Question**

Is there a way to perform this task using pure `Numpy` which eliminates the `for` loop and performs more quickly on large datasets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try to use the column 0 of `a` to index `b` values (sorry not sure of the term here) and then use `hstack` like:

```
c = np.hstack([a, b[a[:, 0], 1:]])
print (c)
[[  0  13 415 666]
 [  0  14 415 666]
 [  1  15 286 583]
 [  1  16 286 583]
 [  2  17 777  32]]
```

Comment: Excellent!  My real world version of the example is all floats, so I had errors "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type".  A more general solution is ``c = np.hstack([a, b[a[:, 0].astype(int), 1:]])``